# How is the control surface configuration of predator/reaper for redundancy system?

Tags: flight-controls, control-surfaces, redundancy, mq-9-reaper

In commercial aircraft like Airbus or Boeing, there are several control surfaces that work in the same function such as for roll control capability, the control surfaces are aileron and spoiler. Also just like (Correct me if i'm wrong) HSTAB trim as backup of elevator. Because of course it is used for redundancy hence there are no single failure lead to catastrophic. But i read that predator and reaper do not have spoiler. So how the configuration of predator/reaper control surface to accommodate "no single failure lead to catastrophic" in term of control surface failure

Thank you

Comment: Why would they need redundancy? It's not like it's going to kill hundreds of passengers if it crashes.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Okay, but according to CS 23 Special Condition rev 3 [link](https://www.easa.europa.eu/sites/default/files/dfu/SC-RPAS.1309-03_Iss01_FOR%20CONSULTATION.pdf) related to RPAS, still, if the RPAS fly into civilian airspace and crash due to erroneous of roll control resulting one or more fatalities, it is still considered Catastrophic. But even below it, which is hazardous, the case is loss of RPAS control capability, which i think the accommodate hazardous type function, redundancy is still required.

Comment: Why would this be relevant? Has General Atomics applied for a civilian European Type Certificate? I can't even imagine what a civilian use of a. Reaper would be.

Comment: There is redundancy. And, then there are work arounds. The examples that you gave sound more like work arounds. They are systems meant for another purpose that can be utilized as a last resort. For instance, trim tabs are not meant as backups to primary control surfaces. They can be used as such in a pinch. But, that is not their primary function. Saying that, many small aircraft do not have trim tabs on every control surface. Nor, do they have spoilers. Safe flight is still accomplished. Military drones are not large aircraft compared to Airbus and Boeing aircraft.

Comment: Plus, reread section 3 in the document you attached. https://www.easa.europa.eu/sites/default/files/dfu/SC-RPAS.1309-03_Iss01_FOR%20CONSULTATION.pdf  This section alone makes the rest of the document only applicable to the advanced technology used to make drones possible. It does not apply to the more tried and true technology common to basic aircraft. In other words, drones have to follow the certification process of your basic aircraft for normal flight as if they are manned. Plus, they have to adhere to further requirements only for those components needed specifically for unmanned flight.

Comment: You may note that redundancy is also provided by several control surfaces moved by different hydraulic circuit (e.g. multiple spoilers, each pair being connected to different hydraulic circuit)

Comment: I don't think “no single failure lead to catastrophic” is ever actually true. E.g. main rotor gearbox in a helicopter is a single point of failure, as are many structural elements. The real requirement is that probability of a critical failure must be qualified to less than once in 10⁹ hours and that can probably be done with independent actuators on the single surface. It is what is done for the rudder and there are aircraft that have stabilatosr, e.g. Lockheed L-1011 TriStar, so they don't have any second surface for pitch control either.